# Use an IF STATEMENT with INSERT IGNORE

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, insert

I have a voting system, which users can use to vote on posts. Thing is, they can't vote twice on the same post. Which is good. I did that like this:

```
$query  = "INSERT IGNORE INTO vote_id (vote, postid, userid) 
        VALUES ('1', '{$postid}', '{$userid}')";    
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
header('Location: index.php');
```

(The `$db` is my variable that connects to the database.)

They can still click on the vote, even if it doesn't insert into the table. The problem is, when it is `IGNORE` they shouldn't be able to click.

How do I separate the `INSERT` and `IGNORE`, so I can use the `IGNORE` in an `if` statement? Or in any other way, that can change the layout of the page?

Comment: You're thinking about it a little oddly. What you can do is store some session information or a cookie about 'this' user. Once 'this' user has voted you update the session or cookie with some information and use that to disable the voting mechanism. They *could* clear their cookie or session though, so you'll want to store some identifying information in the database. When they click to vote check the database for that identifying information first - if they've voted you can stop it from occurring. An `IGNORE` on the database side cannot interact with the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Without code showing "vote" it's hard to say, but if it's button, then you can simply query a `SELECT` for a `user_id` *and* `post_id`, and if it finds at least one row, then add `disabled` to button. Like that:

```
<button name="vote" value="1" disabled>Vote</button>
```

Or just don't display anything "to vote" at all when query returns rows.

Other way is to check session, but it'd let the same user to vote again after relogging.

Answer (score 0):

> Thing is, they can't vote twice on the same post. Which is good. I did that like this:

What you've shown us here doesn't prevent people from voting twice (a unique index on postid and userid will - but that's not in your post). I do hope you are cleaning those parameters before splicing them into a an SQL statement like that.

But that is a comment.

> How do I separate the INSERT and IGNORE, so I can use the IGNORE in an if statement

While I'm not 100% certain, I would expect mysqli_affected_rows() to return 0 if no rows were inserted. A more robust solution would be to omit the 'IGNORE' from the SQL statement and handle the duplicate key error:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$error=mysqli_errno($db);
switch ($error) {
   case 0:
       // all good
       header('Location: index.php');
       break;
   case 1062:
       print "Please don't vote twice\n";
       exit;
   default:
       trigger_error("Query failed " . $query . " // " . mysqli_error($db));
       print "whoops";
       exit;
   }
```